# getStaticProps return an empty array

Tags: api, next.js, axios, getstaticprops

hi i'm trying to do a twitch clone with Nextjs,

i'm trying to fetch the twith api with what NextJs offer: getStaticProps so i wrote a code like this but it doesn't work, it return me an empty array and i don't understand why

here is my code :

```
type Props = {};

function Games({}: Props, props:any) {
console.log(props)

  return (
    <div>
    </div>
);
}

    export async function getStaticProps() {
        
        try {
            const url: string = "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/games/top";
            const resp = await api.get(url);
            const data = await resp?.data;
    
            return {
                props: {
                    data:data
                }
            }
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

the api variable is code like that :

```
import axios from 'axios'

let api = axios.create({
    headers:{
        'Client-ID': process.env.TWITCH_API_KEY,
        'Authorization' :`Bearer ${process.env.TWITCH_BEARER}`
    }
})

export default api
```

when i try with post man with the same url, client-id and bearer i got a response 200 with all of the top games so why it doesn't work with get static props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the `data` prop to the `Games` component. You are declaring that Games should require a `data` prop.

Documentation: [Next.JS/Data Fetching/getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props)

Stripping the component down to bare bones, we get:

```
export default function Games({ data }) {
  console.log(data);
  return <div>Games Component</div>;
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const data = res;
  return {
    props: {
      data: data,
    },
  };
}
```

Then in a page (where the component is rendered), we can pass `data` as such:

```
import Games from "./games";

export default function Page() {
  //mocked API response
  const responseData = [{ game1: "A Game" }, { game2: "Another Game" }];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Page</h1>
// passing `data` to `Games`
      <Games data={responseData} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now the console log appears as expected.

As an aside, I'd recommend rethinking the TypeScript implementation. You may want to remove the type declaration, since you also have an inline type declaration. You could also implement an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html), instead.